# My while loop is not working on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

my teacher sent me an excercise and I need help to solve it. It's about making a shopping list. When you press the button cancel, the elements you add should be displayed on the website but it doesn't happen. Please, I need help.

```
<body>
<h1>SHOPPING EVERYWHERE!</h1>
 <script>
 var lista = prompt('Introduce element to add');
  while (lista != null) {
   document.write('<li>' + lista + '</li>');
   l = prompt('Introduce element to add');
  }
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You check a "lista" but you read an "l"

Comment: Please post the complete code.

Comment: You are my savior. THANK YOU!

Comment: Don't ever use `document.write` unless you know **very precisely** what it does. Also `<li>` elements can only live inside `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `lista` will never change in the loop because you never change the variable `lista`. I think your issue was that you wrote `l` in the loop and not `lista`, so may write:

```html
<body>
<h1>SHOPPING EVERYWHERE!</h1>
<script>
 var lista = prompt('Introduce element to add');
  while (lista != null) {
   document.write('<li>' + lista + '</li>');
   lista = prompt('Introduce element to add');
  }
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This creates **invalid HTML**. `<li>` elements can only live inside `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements.